# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule returns 404 status but produces a page

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, response

I'm developing a plugin for Wordpress and it utilizes custom permalinks.

I use `add_rewrite_rule()` as such:
`add_rewrite_rule('^collection/sku/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=single_item&sku=$matches[1]', 'top');`

When I go to a url such as `/collection/sku/123` it displays fine, however I notice in the inspector it returns a 404 status.  I have never seen this before and I'm a bit confused how I can get a 404 yet still have a page that seems to display without issue.

I get the same kind of result using the Facebook debugger.  It says there is a 404 response code, but it still scrapes all the information.

I do call `flush_rewrite_rules()` at the end of the initialization process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after looking a lot I found a solution, maybe is not the correct one but it works and now returns a 200 status code instead of 404.

In the function that returns the correct template for the page I've added:

```
status_header(200);
```

The whole example:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'include_template');
    public function include_template( $template )
    {
        $page = get_query_var('pagename');

        if ( $page == 'participantes')
        {
          status_header(200);
          return trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'page-participantes.php';
        }

        return $template;
    }
```